# I want to close all open windows and files through batch file

Tags: window, batch-file

Right now, I am closing all the opened windows. I want to write a batch file which will close all the opened files and windows on just double clicking the batch file.
Please guide me for this.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I want to close all the windows automatically which are opened 

Can anybody please provide me the code?

If anybody having sample program please give me.

Comment: i havent tried yet . please guide me how to start as i am new to this

Comment: You can use the taskkill command in a batch file to kill a particular process: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009

Comment: Great, I moved my comment to an answer, can you please mark as resolved?

Comment: can u please tell me how to mark as resolved as i am new to this .

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111630/how-to-mark-a-question-on-so-as-resolved. Also you can upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the taskkill command in a batch file to kill a particular process: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009